# Combining two texture in fragment shader

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl

I'm working on implementing deferred shading to my game. I have rendered the diffuse textures to a render target, and I have lighting rendered to a render target. Both of which I know are fine because I can render them straight to the screen with no problems. What I want to do is combine both the diffuse map and the light map in a shader to create a final image. Here is my current fragment shader, which results in a black screen.

```
#version 110

uniform sampler2D diffuseMap;
uniform sampler2D lightingMap;

void main()
{
    vec4 color = texture(diffuseMap, gl_TexCoord[0].st);
    vec4 lighting = texture(lightingMap, gl_TexCoord[0].st);

    vec4 finalColor = color;

    gl_FragColor = finalColor;
}
```

Shouldn't this result in the same thing as just straight up drawing the diffuse map?

I set the sampler2d with this method

```
void ShaderProgram::setUniformTexture(const std::string& name, GLint t) {
    GLint var = getUniformLocation(name);
    glUniform1i(var, t);
}

GLint ShaderProgram::getUniformLocation(const std::string& name) {
    if(mUniformValues.find(name) != mUniformValues.end()) {
        return mUniformValues[name];
    }

    GLint var = glGetUniformLocation(mProgram, name.c_str());
    mUniformValues[name] = var;

    return var;
}
```

EDIT: Some more information. Here is the code where I use the shader. I set the two textures, and draw a blank square for the shader to use. I know for sure, my render targets are working, as I said before, because I can draw them fine using the same getTextureId as I do here.

```
    graphics->useShader(mLightingCombinedShader);
    mLightingCombinedShader->setUniformTexture("diffuseMap", mDiffuse->getTextureId());
    mLightingCombinedShader->setUniformTexture("lightingMap", mLightMap->getTextureId());
    graphics->drawPrimitive(mScreenRect, 0, 0);
        graphics->clearShader();



void GraphicsDevice::useShader(ShaderProgram* p) {
    glUseProgram(p->getId());
}

void GraphicsDevice::clearShader() {
    glUseProgram(0);
}
```

And the vertex shader

```
#version 110 

varying vec2 texCoord;

void main() 
{ 
    texCoord = gl_MultiTexCoord0.xy;
    gl_Position = ftransform();

}
```

Comment: Before combining two textures, make sure you can get *one* texture to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem ended up being that I didn't enable the texture coordinates for the screen rectangle I was drawing.

Answer (score 1):

In GLSL version 110 you should use:

```
texture2D(diffuseMap, gl_TexCoord[0].st); // etc.
```

instead of just the texture function.

And then to combine the textures, just multiply the colours together, i.e.

```
gl_FragColor = color * lighting;
```

Comment: You haven't really given enough information for us to be able to help you sort out that problem. Although when you do get a texture showing up, the multiplication of the colours should work

Comment: Okay. I added some more info to my op, but not really sure what info to provide. Since the shader seems to be fine, the problem must be in passing the textures to the shader? Could it be that I can't pass VBO textures to the shader?

Comment: @rcapote Hmm... Can you test whether something draws at all? Simplify your shader code to just `gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0)` (i.e. just draw white). If you've got a white box on the screen then we're halfway there to solving the problem

Comment: Yes, setting a color like that works fine. I did a bit more reading on the topic and found out that I have to assign the texture to a texture unit using `glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0); glBindTexture(...); glUniformValue1i(var, 0);` before I can use it in the shader. That gave me a gray color, but not much else.

Comment: @rcapote Does it give you grey for all the textures?

Comment: The diffuseMap is gray, and the lightingMap is black

Answer (score 0):

```
glUniform1i(var, t);
```

The `glUniform` functions affect the program that is *currently* in use. That is, the last program that `glUseProgram` was called on. If you want to set the uniform for a specific program, you have to use it first.

Comment: Yep, I set the values after I use program.